# Problem during GenerateDSYMFile process (exit code 0)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cicd, dwarf

I am getting a strange message during the compilation of one of our modules while using xcodebuild (Ventura 13.4.1 and Xcode 14.3.1) in C++:

error: the following command failed with ****exit code 0**** but produced no further output this happens

GenerateDSYMFile /path/to/file.(file extension).dSYM /path/to/file.(file extension) (in target 'file (macOS)' from project 'file')

It generates all the files correct. So I am able to see the debug symbols if I use the dsym file.

We see that for some of other project too. I could not find what could be the reason, can you help here ?

(its happening only when it's triggered in CI/CD system by a runner, the local builds are fine)

The interesting part is it exits with error code 0 (AFAIK, exit 0 is not an error for the standard practices).